# Laravel sort database using specified child column and order by specified child column

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm have got a problem about showing data with multi relation table,
I just want show data from **jadwal** table with specified value from **kelas.nama_kelas** and sort it by **jam.waktu_mulai**,

for example : Showing data from **jadwal** where has **nama_kelas**=3C

this my model.php

```
    public function dosen(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Dosen','id');
   }

   public function jurusan(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jurusan','id');
   }

   public function ruang(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ruang','id');
   }

   public function kelas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Kelas','id');
   }

   public function makul(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Matakuliah','id');
   }

   public function hari(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Hari','id');
   }

   public function jam(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Jam','id');
   }
```

This my controller.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $dec = $id;
    $sort = \App\Kelas::find($dec);
    $jadwals = Jadwal::join('dosen','dosen.nip','=','jadwal.nip')
                    ->join('jurusan','jurusan.kode_jurusan','=','jadwal.kode_jurusan')
                    ->join('ruang','ruang.kode_ruang','=','jadwal.kode_ruang')
                    ->join('kelas','kelas.kode_kelas','=','jadwal.kode_kelas')
                    ->join('mata_kuliah','mata_kuliah.kode_mk','=','jadwal.kode_mk')
                    ->join('hari','hari.kode_hari','=','jadwal.kode_hari')
                    ->join('jam','jam.kode_jam','=','jadwal.kode_jam')
                    ->select('*','jadwal.id as jadwal_id','kelas.id as kelas_id')
                    ->where('kelas.nama_kelas','LIKE','%'.$sort->nama_kelas.'%')
                    ->orderBy('jam.waktu_mulai','Asc')
                    ->get();

    return view('Akademik.Jadwal.jadwalDetail',compact('jadwals')); 
}
```

And this my database entiti reltion diagram :
[image]

sorry for my bad english

**EDIT 1:**
I have been test and do a research it works but when i try to print $jadwal->kelas_id it return nul...but not for $jadwal->jadwal_id,,,

Comment: And what issue you are getting or what is the issue ?

Comment: thanks before for comment, now the problem is **$jadwal->kelas_id** going return null,,,can U help me?